# Is there a Atlas api call to get the status of terraform run?

Tags: terraform

I am using atlas to execute my terraform files. I configured terraform remote to my atlas environment and then used terraform push to upload my files. This action invoked atlas to execute the terraform and created my aws resources successfully after 2 mins. I would like to automate this process and am looking for atlas api calls to get the status of my run.

I couldn't find anything in their documentation. Is it possible to get the run status via an api call ?

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Response from Hashicorp support:

Here is the extent of the [Terraform API](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/help/api/terraform). You are able to queue plans, but at this time retrieving the status of the of a plan/apply is not possible.